# EF6 change database create strategy

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I have an application where I want to use the **FILESTREAM** feature for storing blobs. I know that EF6 does not support **FILESTREAM**, so I will manage file and image handling by myself. However, I have to write my own initialize code to add a **FILEGROUP** and **FILE** to my Database and:

```
public class CustomDbInitializer : CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<DatenbankContext>
{   
    public override void InitializeDatabase(DatenbankContext context)
    {
        base.InitializeDatabase(context);
        SqlConnectionStringBuilder b = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(context.Database.Connection.ConnectionString);
        context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(TransactionalBehavior.DoNotEnsureTransaction,"ALTER DATABASE "+ b.InitialCatalog + " ADD FILEGROUP GRP CONTAINS FILESTREAM");
        //more sql commands
    }
}
```

Then, I call manually the function **InitializeDatabase(context)**

```
new CustomDbInitializer().InitializeDatabase(context);
```

However, I find this a bit clunky and counter-intuitive. I know that I can set an initializer for the context in the constructor, but this does not work the way I want:

```
public class DatenbankContext : DbContext
{
    public DatenbankContext()
        :base("name=name")
    {
        Database.SetInitializer(new CustomDbInitializer());
    }
}
```

Basically, I want the call

```
new DatenbankContext() // or
context.Database.CreateIfNotExists()
```

to initialize my Database with my custom strategy in an intuitive way. How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

Inside your custom initializer add:

```
if (!context.Database.Exists())
{
    context.Database.Create();
}
// Do next steps
```

Call your initializer inside a static constructor. This insures it only runs once:

```
public class DatenbankContext : DbContext
{
    static DatenbankContext()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer(new CustomDbInitializer());
    }
}
```

See [here](https://www.codeguru.com/csharp/article.php/c19999/Understanding-Database-Initializers-in-Entity-Framework-Code-First.htm) for more on custom initializers. You probably don't want to inherit from `CreateDatabaseIfNotExists` if you want control over the process. See the example in link.

Comment: The problem with this solution is, that the initializer is not called when the context is created. It is called when you "touch" the database with i.e `context.Table.Add(...)`. That is to late for me.

Comment: Then call `context.Database.Initialize(true);` in your startup. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.database.initialize(v=vs.113).aspx